# Pandas: How to maintain the type of columns with nan?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example,I have a `df` with `nan` and use the following method to `fillna`.

```
import pandas as pd 
a = [[2.0, 10, 4.2], ['b', 70, 0.03], ['x',  ]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df)

df.fillna(int(0),inplace=True)
print('fillna df\n',df)
dtype_df = df.dtypes.reset_index()
```

OUTPUT:

```
   0     1     2
0  2  10.0  4.20
1  b  70.0  0.03
2  x   NaN   NaN
fillna df
    0     1     2
0  2  10.0  4.20
1  b  70.0  0.03
2  x   0.0  0.00
   col     type
0    0   object
1    1  float64
2    2  float64
```

Actually,I want the `column 1` maintain the type of `int` instead of `float`.

My desired output:

```
fillna df
    0     1     2
0  2  10  4.20
1  b  70  0.03
2  x   0  0.00

   col     type
0    0   object
1    1  int64
2    2  float64
```

So how to do it?

Comment: You have an error in the last line of your example: you apparently used `fillna(0)`, not `ffill(0)`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the error!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `downcast='infer'` to downcast any eligible columns:

```
df.fillna(0, downcast='infer')

   0   1     2
0  2  10  4.20
1  b  70  0.03
2  x   0  0.00
```

And the corresponding `dtypes` are

```
0     object
1      int64
2    float64
dtype: object
```